# How to get axios to use server-side caching?

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I am currently buiding an application with a Laravel API and a Vuejs frontend. For the API I am using the `spatie/laravel-responsecache` package to handle caching.

If I visit a url directly e.g. `http://api.mysite.com/users` then it fetches the data and caches it correctly.

However, if a url e.g. `http://api.mysite.com/messages` (one that I have not directly visited) is fetched via axios on the frontend, it is not cached. Again, if I then go and visit it directly, its cached, and then if I fetch it from the frontend it is cached.

How can I force axios to use the server side caching without me having to preload the url?

Comment: Server side caching should be done in your php code. `axios` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Jerodev Not necessarily, the request can include cache control headers.

Comment: @jeroen but that's client side caching :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [default caching profile](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache/blob/master/src/CacheProfiles/CacheAllSuccessfulGetRequests.php) you can see that it `ignores ajax requests`.

Copy this file, move it to your own code, remove:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
   return false;
}
```

Then update the `config/response_cache.php` file and point the `cache_profile` entry to your file.